# How do I provide implicit arguments explicitly in Coq?

Tags: coq

Suppose I have a definition `f : x -> y -> z` where `x` can be easily inferred.
I therefore choose to make `x` an implicit argument using `Arguments`.

Consider the following example:

```
Definition id : forall (S : Set), S -> S :=
fun S s => s.

Arguments id {_} s.

Check (id 1).
```

Clearly `S = nat` can be and is inferred by Coq, and Coq replies:

```
id 1
     : nat
```

However, at a later time, I want to make the implicit argument explicit, say, for readability.

In other words, I would like something like:

```
Definition foo :=
 id {nat} 1. (* We want to make it clear that the 2nd argument is nat*)
```

Is this possible at all?
If so, what is the appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can prepend the name with `@` to remove all implicits and provide them explicitly:

```
Check @id nat 1.
```

You can also use `(a:=v)` to pass an implicit argument by name. This can both clarify what argument is being passed and also allows you to pass some implicits without passing `_` for the others:

```
Check id (S:=nat) 1.

Definition third {A B C:Type} (a:A) (b:B) (c:C) := c.
Check third (B:=nat) (A:=unit) tt 1 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is by prepending `@` to the definition.
For example:

```
Definition id : forall (S : Set), S -> S :=
fun S s => s.

Arguments id {_} s.

Check @id nat 1.
```

Which results in:

```
id 1
     : nat
```